# How can I convert bigint to hours and minutes in SQL?

Tags: sql, timestamp, converters, bigint

I have the following problem: I have a database with a `BIGINT` column and I am trying to convert this to an hour, so my database looks like this

```
id minutes hours and minutes 
------------------------------
1   400       null
2   450       null
3   421       null
4   140       null
```

I need to convert my minutes that is saved as a `bigint` to hours and minutes; how can I do this the best way?

I need this result

```
 id minutes hours and minutes 
 ----------------------------
    1   400       06:40
    2   450       07:30
    3   421       null
    4   140       null
```

I am new to this I googled but I couldn't find a answer to my question could someone help me or give me a link - how I can do this? Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Why is `421` converted to `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the hours and minutes using arithmetic:

```
select floor(minutes_col / 60) as hours,
       minutes_col % 60 as minutes
```

Some databases use `mod()` for the modulo function.

Converting to a string is highly database-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

SQL has datatype specially for saving time: **time(n)** **(n can be between 0-7)** [Check here for more info about this datatype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

Your third column should be of this type. 
Then you can calculate hours and minutes from your minutes column values like below:

hours = totalminuts/60 and minutes = totalminutes%60. 
Then save 'Hour:minutes' in third column.

Hope this helps.